# OPA (Open Policy Agent) loading bundle from S3 to local workstation

Tags: open-policy-agent

I'm trying to run OPA container locally to load the bundle from an S3 bucket but it keeps failing with the below error. What am I missing?

**Command:**

```
docker run -v ${CUR_DIR}/config-new.yaml:/config-new.yaml -e AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN} -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} -e AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=${AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE} -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} artifactory-dockerhub.cloud.capitalone.com/openpolicyagent/opa:latest run --server --log-level debug --config-file /config-new.yaml
```

**Error:**

```
{"level":"error","msg":"Bundle load failed: request failed: error getting AWS credentials: metadata endpoint cannot be determined from settings and environment","name":"authz","plugin":"bundle","time":"2021-06-22T18:08:56Z"}
```

**config file:**

```
labels:
  app: opa-bundle-poc
  region: us-east-1
  environment: dev

services:
  bundle-policy:
    url: https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<dir1>
    credentials:
      s3_signing:
        metadata_credentials:
          aws_region: us-east-1

bundles:
  authz:
    service: bundle-policy
    resource: bundle/opa-bundle-poc.tar.gz
    polling:
     min_delay_seconds: 10
     max_delay_seconds: 20

decision_logs:
  service: bundle-policy
  console: true

status:
  service: bundle-policy
```

**Edit:**
Based on the input from @Devoops, I made the below change and then I'm able to download the bundle as expected from S3 to local.

```
    services:
          bundle-policy:
            url: https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<dir1>
            credentials:
              s3_signing:
                metadata_credentials:
 -------->        environment_credentials: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's just for the example, but I believe this:

```
url: s3://<bucket>/<dir1>
```

should rather be the `https` URL of the bucket. Does changing that make a difference?

Comment: Oops. That was typo. I'm using the right url in my local but no luck yet.
Also, corrected the question.

Comment: Ah, OK! Taking another glance at your config, this won't work locally. the metadata service config is only available from inside AWS EC/ECS. You'll need another way of securing your bundle endpoint if you want it to be accessed from the outside.

Comment: Is there any other way by which we can get the bundle load from S3 configured for local. Using aws credentials?

Comment: Yes, use credentials stored in the environment: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/configuration/#using-static-environment-credentials

Comment: Thank You so much @Devoops. Not sure how I missed looking at it. The choice to have it as an empty object puzzles but it works. Thank You, I will update the question with your suggestion.

Comment: Agreed on the empty object. I think originally meant to hold more attributes, but so far hasn't been needed :)